# Trouble with PHP sessions for including langauge files

Tags: php, debugging

I'm trying to rework my company's old website. Currently it supports two languages - English and Hebrew. The way it works is that it simply runs include_once on a language file "lang_en.php" or "lang_he.php" depending on what is contained in $_SESSION['lang'], which would be either 'en' or 'he'.

Right now I'm working on the first pages - Index.php (homepage), Login.php and Register.php. All 3 of them start out exactly alike with a bit of a nested include call.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php
include '../Common/HtmlHead.php';
?>
```

The file HtmlHead.php is where I run session_start(), include the file LanguageParser and do some other  buildup for the html part of the pages.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("../../Controller/Config.php");
include_once("../../Tests/ObjectModels/ServerResponse.php");
include_once("../../Tests/ObjectModels/Users/User.php");

include_once("../Language/LanguageParser.php");
?>
```

Then finally is the file LanguageParser.php which looks into GET and SESSION and determines which language file to run include_once on:

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}

// Include Language file
if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $langFile ="lang_" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Logic/SmartView/Language/".$langFile)) {
        include_once $langFile;
    } else {
        include_once "lang_en.php";
    }
} else {
    include_once "lang_en.php";
}
```

Yet for some reason, the language saved in $_SESSION['lang'] just doesn't seem to stick. Each page behaves as if it has its own session with its own language saved. Even if I change language, navigate to another page, then navigate back, the language reverts.

Answer (score 2):

The session cannot start when some output has been sent to the client. You can make a trick and use `$_SESSION` before any `HTML` or `echo` call.

LanguageParser.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$lang = 'en';
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo $lang?>">

<?php
include '../Common/HtmlHead.php';
?>
```

HtmlHead.php

```
// Include Language file
$langFile ="lang_" .$lang . ".php";
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Logic/SmartView/Language/".$langFile)) {
    include_once $langFile;
} else {
    include_once "lang_en.php";
}
```

Comment: it's not a *trick* to call session_start() before sending output, it's required because it sets a cookie. You don't necessarily need to use $_SESSION before output

Comment: Ok, yup, that did it! I had no idea about having to call session_start before sending output to the client, but it makes sense in hindsight (can you tell im still a beginner to PHP?). Thank you very much!